# store session cart to database

Tags: codeigniter, session, shopping-cart

Sorry for asking this old questions, and I know that I've read before I ask here, it's can use database for adding more cart without limitation. I already try to use ci_sessions table to store session but still no luck, I only can adding 6 items maximum.

please help me, I looking for some example for this almost two days and result is nothing

**EDITED**
this is my view

```
<table id="box-table-a" summary="Employee Pay Sheet">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Description</th>
                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                <th class="centered" scope="col">Options</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($foto_produk->result() as $key => $value) {?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $value->description;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $value->price;?></td>
                <td class="centered"><input type="checkbox" name="produk_foto[]" value="<?php echo $value->id;?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <?php }?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

here's my controller code

```
if($this->input->post('produk_foto')){
       $id_foto = $this->input->post('produk_foto');
       foreach ($id_foto as $key => $value) {

           $this->db->where('id', $value);
           $query = $this->db->get('foto_product');
           if($query->num_rows() > 0){
               foreach($query->result() as $ids => $rows){              
                   echo $rows->id.'<br />';
                   $data_produk = array(
                       'user_data'=> array(
                            'id' => $rows->id, 
                            'price' => $rows->price,
                            'name' => $rows->description,
                            'qty' => $rows->aantal
                        )
                   );

                   $this->cart->insert($data_produk);
               }            
           }
       }
    }
```

and this my view code

```
<?php if(!$this->cart->contents()):?>
    <div class="alert-box warning">The regular products are empty.</div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <?php else:?>
    <hr>
    <h4>REGULAR PRODUCTS</h4>
    <div class="order_detail" id="Display">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
                    <th>QUANTITY</th>
                    <th>PRICE PER ITEM(S)</th>
                    <th>TOTAL</th>
                    <th>REMOVE</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                 <?php foreach($this->cart->contents() as $rows):?>
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $rows['name'];?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?php echo form_open(current_url());?>
                        <input type="text" size="3" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $rows['qty'];?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" size="3" name="rowid" value="<?php echo $rows['rowid'];?>" />
                        <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update" />
                        <?php echo form_close();?>
                    </td>
                    <td><?php echo $rows['price'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $this->cart->format_number($rows['subtotal']);?></td>
                    <td><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/en/payment/delete_item_product/'.$rows['rowid'].'');?>">delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">Total Products</td>
                    <td colspan="3">&euro; <?php echo $this->cart->format_number($this->cart->total());?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">Total Shipping</td>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"></td>
                    <td colspan="3" style="padding:0;text-align:center;">
                        <p>TOTAL :</p>
                        <span class="tot">&euro; <?php echo $this->cart->format_number($this->cart->total());?></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php endif;?>
```

with this code I want to insert using checkbox with array, and I have more than 6 checkbox

thank you in advance

Comment: what is the error you are facing because you said you tried......

Comment: @Alessandro Minoccheri I was tried to insert more cart, but I always have 6 maximum items adding

Comment: @Venkat no error here, but I want insert more than 6 items..

Comment: I cannot help you without code

Comment: @Alessandro Minoccheri I already post my code

Comment: Post your html/view I have a doubt in It

Comment: in your view there isn't produk_foto

Comment: @AlessandroMinoccheri yup, produk_foto is in other view, and I already edit my post, please check it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it's solved by my self..

I don't know that in the name of product there are special characters..

and shame of me..

but thank you anyway